# Fuzzy/flex/scatter string matching

Tags: string-matching, fuzzy-search, scatter

Everybody has seen "fuzzy" string matching used by Textmate to search files (also by emacs' ido/icicles, vim's Command-T, Sublime Text 2, XCode etc) by entering partial path/name of a file (possibly not entering whole name, just some parts). This is also popularized by applications like QuickSilver, LaunchBar and Alfred.

So I'm wondering if there is any ideas how do I build an index which will speed up such a matching? I have list of thousands of strings (around 7k right now - list of songs from iTunes), and I'd like to match them fast. Right now I've just taken QuickSilver scoring algorithm which on certain queries can take 5 seconds to perform.

Any ideas how do I speed up this are welcome.